# How to express nearly convex function in terms of Hessian?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

A function $f:R^2\rightarrow R$ is called nearly convex if for any two points $x,y\in R^2$ there exists $t\in (0,1)$ such that
$$f((1-t)x+ty)\leq (1-t)f(x)+tf(y).$$ We know that if a function is convex then its Hessian is positive semidefinite. But how can we express the nearly convex function in terms of Hessian?

Comment: It seems to me that any nearly convex $f \in C^2(\mathbb R^2)$ is in fact convex. Do you know any counterexample?

Comment: @Michał Miśkiewicz: would the function $|x|$ for $x\ne0$ and $x=1$ for $x=0$ be nearly convex?

Comment: @mic You're right, that's an interesting example. Although this is not differentiable (twice).

Comment: I also have the same doubt as @MichałMiśkiewicz. Please clarify it.
To show any result on Hessian, you have to ensure that the function is twice differentiable. Unless until it is mentioned, you can not assume it.

Comment: I agree with @MichałMiśkiewicz. This seems like an extension of what is known as _midpoint convexity_. A function is said to be _midpoint convex_ if for any $x,y$, the inequality holds for $t=0.5$. But it is known that midpoint convexity is equivalent to convexity. It's not clear to me that this would be any different.

Comment: _"We know that if a function is convex then its Hessian is positive semidefinite."_ This is false. As @mlc points out, $f(x)=|x|$ is convex, and yet its Hessian does not even exist at $x=0$. The opposite implication is true, but not this one.